# How to set the background color of a search container put into a blue top bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a search field on my website's topbar and all my attempts to style it have failed. Topbar and topbar icons background color are blue (#6495ed) as it should be, the icons are white (as it should be), but the search container stays white. How to set it blue?

As the search input and button are placed in a search container (= a div), I have set background:#6495ed of the button and its container. I have modified several times their margin, their padding, but I haven't figured out the proper combination.

I've set a JsFiddle and weird, I can't reproduce the problem within JsFiddle! Why, strange isn't it?
https://jsfiddle.net/r5uqb8v0/1/ 

So this picture should explain.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1idQKbtKHaOT-QXByAMw1tXR9l9owMUlc/view?usp=sharing 
It's same problem on Chrome and Firefox.
I'm coding on a Windows 10, running MySQL 5.7.22, PHP 7.2.4 and Apache 2.4.33 (WampServer).

This is the search field HTML :

```
<div class="item3 search-container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
   <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

As for the CSS :

```
.topnav .search-container {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  background: #6495ed;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.topnav .search-container input {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  display: none;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  cursor: pointer;
}
.topnav .search-container button {
  font-size: 1.875em;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: #6495ed;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
}
```

Topbar and topbar icons background color are blue (#6495ed) as it should be, the icons are white (as it should be), but the search container stays white (this is the problem). 

Any suggestion would be very appreciated! Thank you already for reading!
 
Best regards
 
Samuel

Comment: I'm not even seeing the search input field due to `display:none`

Comment: Hi Jon, later when I'll click on the search button, the search field will be displayed (some JS I haven't written yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samuel.
It seems that the code worked locally. I used your JsFiddle code locally and the specified issue could not be replicated. Please refer to the attached screenshot. Be assured, your code works fine.[Click to view this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AfFR.png)

[At times browsers on our systems make the situation go haywire. It's advised to check if it's updated and you can even try re-installing the browser.]

Comment: Hi Umang, thanks for your reply. I read this in the about section : Google Chrome is up to date Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (32-bit). Have we got the same version?

Comment: Umang, after creating a html file and a css file with just the code I provided I could notice that yes it works fine. So the problem comes from the other piece of code of those files. I'm going to reorganise the code. BR, Bye!

Comment: Sure. I'd also recommend you to post the error and solution (if found) here so that if someone else faces the same issue can get the solution a bit quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your style properties inside the

For example`<i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>`

fa fa -car - is a font awesome icon class i used above.

Just use style properties inside the `<i>`

Comment: Hi Jeyam, thanks for your suggestion. I'll check if it solve anything.